# Is it true $\mu (A+B) = \mu (A) + \mu(B) $ for bounded sets $ A, B \subset R $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Is it true $\mu (A+B) = \mu (A) + \mu(B) $ for bounded sets $ A, B \subset R $ where $\mu $ is Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: By $A+B$, you mean the Minkowski sum, i.e. $A+B := \{ a+b : a\in A, b\in B\}$, yes?  I'm not convinced that this is even true: consider $A = [0,1]$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\mu(A) = 1$, $\mu(B) = 0$, and $\mu(A+B) = \infty$.  Brunn-Minkowski requires compactness---do you have that?

Comment: This result only appears to be true if $A,B$ are disjoint. Otherwise we have the inequality which you obtained

Comment: @JonStaggs: Why do you state that?

Comment: @copper.hat I believe that it follows straight from the definition of the Lebesgue measure https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf

Comment: @JonStaggs: What follows from the definition of the Lebesgue measure? You need to give an example of $A,B$ in the line that do not satisfy the statement. The result is true if $A,B$ are intervals, for example.

Comment: @XanderHenderson compactness not needed but the sets need to be bounded.

Comment: You might want to consider phrasing the question as "Is it true that..." rather than "How to show..." which suggests that it is true.

Comment: $A=[-2, -1]$ and $B=[1,2]$.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah rephrasing needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A=[0,1] \cup [2,3], B=[0,2]$.

Then $A+B = [0,5]$, but
$\mu^* (A+B) = 5$ whereas $\mu^* A + \mu^* B = 4$.

Comment: Hmmm I was dreaming

Comment: @Abdullahi_A_Ibrahim: This is how we discover new things :-).